# How can store Sessions in Database then call it after log in and destroy when log off in php

Tags: php, database, session, handler, store

Well my code stores the session in the database with no problem but I don't understand how to call it from the database and how to destroy it when the user logs off

My page works like:

To login the user goes for example to the domain ---- xxx.xxxx.com
If the login is correct it redirects them to ANOTHER domain ---- yyyy.com

I don't know how to call the session from the domain yyyy.com after the login

My code to store the session:

File name  ---- MySQLDatabase.class.php

```
<?php
include("Config.inc.php");
class MySQLDatabase{
private $db;
private $hostname;
private $username;
private $password;
private $schema;

function __construct() {
    if(func_num_args() == 0){
        $this->hostname = conf_hostname;
        $this->username = conf_username;
        $this->password = conf_password;
        $this->schema = conf_schema;
    }
    else{
        $params = func_get_args();
        $this->hostname = $params[0];
        $this->username = $params[1];
        $this->password = $params[2];
        $this->schema = $params[3];
    }
    }

    private function open(){
    $this->db = mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this-              >password) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
    mysql_select_db($this->schema, $this->db);
   }

  public function executeQuery($query){
    $this->open();
      $results = mysql_query($query, $this->db) or die ("Error in query:      $query. ".mysql_error());
    return $results;
  }

  public function close(){
    mysql_close($this->db);
  }

 }
 ?>
```

File Name ---- DatabaseSessionHandler.class.php

```
    <?php
include_once ("MySQLDatabase.class.php");

class DatabaseSessionHandler {
private $db;

public function _open($save_path, $session_name) {
    $this -> db = new MySQLDatabase();
    return true;
}

public function _close() {
    $this -> db -> close();
}

function _read($id) {

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

    $query = "SELECT data
            FROM SESSION
            WHERE id = '$id'";

    if ($result = $this -> db -> executeQuery($query)) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            return $record['data'];
        }
    }

    return '';
}

function _write($id, $data) {
    $access = time();

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $access = mysql_real_escape_string($access);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    $query = "REPLACE
            INTO SESSION
            VALUES ('$id', '$access', '$data')";

    return $this -> db -> executeQuery($query);
}

function _destroy($id) {

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

    $query = "DELETE
            FROM SESSION
            WHERE id = '$id'";

    return $this -> db -> executeQuery($query);
}

function _clean($max) {
    $old = time() - $max;
    $old = mysql_real_escape_string($old);

    $query = "DELETE
            FROM SESSION
            WHERE access < '$old'";

    return $this -> db -> executeQuery($query);
}

public function killUserSession($username){
    $query = "delete from SESSION where data like('%userID|s:%\"".       mysql_real_escape_string($username) ."%\";first_name|s:%')";
    $this->db->executeQuery($query);
}

}
?>
```

The code above works with no problem but I don't know how to call the session stored in the database...

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to call the session stored in the database...

Your best resource is to read this page in detail: http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php .  You should change your DatabaseSessionHandler class so that it implements SessionHandlerInterface and then call session_set_save_handler().  Examples are on the page.

Once you have set that up, sessions in the database will be created and destroyed for you automagically.

> To login the user goes for example to the domain ---- xxx.xxxx.com If the login is correct it redirects them to ANOTHER domain ---- yyyy.com
>
> I don't know how to call the session from the domain yyyy.com after the login

You can't really do that in the normal use case because sessions are tied to cookies which don't propagate from site to site.  So you will have to resort to storing the session ID in the URL.  For more information on how to do that, read this page: http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php